# Change color of active navbar dropdown item in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 5.3 to create a navbar that uses green colors. However, active dropdown item in the dropdown menu is showing in Bootstrap's default blue - see screenshot. How do I change the blue color to green?

Menu screenshot

[image: 1]

My custom CSS is as follows:

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link, .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link, .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-item:active {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the html code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```